# How do I populate a linked list using polymorphism?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I have set up a linked list which is composed of a list class and a node class how can I populate the list class with nodes of different classes?

Comment: It depends. Do you mean run-time polymorphism (that is, you want to create heterogeneous lists) or compile-time polymorphism (that is, you want to create multiple lists holding different types, but each list is homogeneous)? The former requires storing pointers, the latter requires using templates.

Comment: Compile time polymorphism for now where different objects would be put into different lists

Comment: @DonRigatone Do you want one list of varying sub-types, or many lists of single types? You've said both so far.

Answer (score 3):

The elements have to be pointers (smart preferably) to avoid slicing. That's the single restriction I see.

```
YourList<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> > myList;

myList.add(new DerivedClassA);
myList.add(new DerivedClassB);
```

Comment: How do you distinguish a smart pointer front a regular pointer in terms of syntax and use?

Comment: @DonRigatone a regular pointer is just a raw, C-style pointer - `X*`. A smart pointer is something like `std::shared_ptr<X>` or `std::unique_ptr<X>` or `boost::shared_ptr<X>`. The semantics is similar (use `->` to access its contents).

Answer (score 0):

> > how can I populate the list class with nodes of different classes? (Compile time polymorphism for now where different objects would be put into different lists)

I assume you currently have something like:

```
class Node {
public:
  Node* next;
  int datum;
  int& GetDatum() { return datum; }
};
class List {
public:
  Node* head;
  int Count();
};
int List::Count() { /* compute length */; return length; }

int main () { List a; List b; }
```

I suppose that you have other, more useful, member functions, but these are enough to demonstrate the point.

You can convert the above code to use compile-time polymorphism through templates:

```
#include <string>

template<class T>
class Node {
public:
  Node* next;
  T datum;
  T& GetDatum() { return datum; }
  };
  template<class T>
  class List {
  public:
    Node<T>* head;
    int Count();
  };
  template<class T>
  int List<T>::Count() { /*...*/; return length; }
  int main () { List<int> a; List<std::string> b; return a.Count(); }
```